# Variable substitution inside a zsh script

Tags: shell, zsh, heredoc

I would like to confirm what I've found in my tests. One of the benefits of quoting the DELIMITER in a `heredoc` is that the content of the `heredoc` is not expanded. The string of text is processed "as is".

However, I would need to, first, substitute variable contents inside the `heredoc`, and then be sure that "those contents" are going to be processed "as is". For example:

```
#!/bin/zsh

y="World"

x="Hello \$y"

cat <<EOF
$x
EOF
```

**Output:**

```
Hello $y
```

Is this, in the general, the case and recommended practice for what I am trying to do ?

EDIT:

Clarification, my goal is to obtain `Hello $y` as output (as in my example). So, I would like to use variable substitution once, and be sure that, if those contents contain variables (as my example), they aren't going to be substituted, and everything is treated as as if I literally pasted that data.

Is this true in general ?

Comment: It really isn't clear from your question, what are you trying to do? Do you want literal `$y` or you want `World`?  What does "those contents are going to be processed as is" mean?

Comment: I'll clarify. Thank you.

Comment: `my goal is to obtain Hello $y as output (as in my example)` So use the code as shown. I do not understand. `Is this true in general ?` is a too broad question. Can you be _very_ more specific? Where is "in general" exactly? `recommended practice for what I am trying to do ?` What you are trying to do? If you want to print the content of the variable, typically use `printf` or `echo`. If you want to print `Hello $y` just `echo 'Hello $y'`

Comment: You don't need `x`, so your question is still unclear. `cat <<EOF
Hello \$y
EOF`

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, I made a minimal reproducible example. I want to use the contents of the heredoc literally, but I can't quote the DELIMITER. Why ? Because I would like to insert the contents of variable `x`. What happens if the contents of `x` variable also contain a variable (like `$y`). I don't want those contents to be expanded. Would that be true in general ? Variable substitution is performed once inside a heredoc ?

Comment: @KamilCuk My example is much more complex, so I made a simple example to illustrate my point.

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear. I did my best. I hope my latest comments clarify my intention.

Comment: Variable substitution is performed on all variables in a heredoc and a string. If you escape the dollar sign it's a dollar literal and not a variable. So it won't be interpolated. I'm still not 100% what generalization you are trying to make, but an escaped `$` is not part of a variable.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, thank you so much. Yes, I just noticed that if I don't escape `y` variable, here: `x="Hello $y"`. The result is: `Hello World`. There is not "one level of interpolation". Everything is interpolated if I don't quote the DELIMITER.

Comment: ``\`` is not a quote, it's an escape. Also `$` is not a DELIMITER.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, sorry ! Yes, I mean `EOF` in my heredoc is the DELIMITER. I should have said "escape the dollar sign".

Comment: You are contradicting yourself: _I want to use the contents of the heredoc literally_  and _I  would like to insert the contents of variable_. The latter restriction means that you do 
**not** want the content literally.

Comment: Yes, @user1934428. You're right. I had a hard time figuring out how to phrase it. I want the _contents_ of variable `x` literally inside the `heredoc`. That's what I should have said.

Comment: Still unclear. Maybe a correct way would be: "In the heredoc, $x should be expanded, but every other variable should not be expanded"?

Comment: @user1934428, I see. Now that I am thinking...could we say that one level of interpolation occurs ? I mean, `$x` is expanded, but if the contents of that expansion contain variables, they are not expanded. Is that right ?

Comment: The contents is never expanded **again**, unless you are doing so explicitly (using `eval` or `envsubst` for instance). I do not understand the question. What effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: @user1934428, perfect. That's what I wanted to know. You could write the answer, now that the question is clarified, if you want. Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to make sure the contents are never expanded **again**.

Comment: To be honest, I find the question a bit "too blurred" for meriting an answer (answers should be useful for the general public). Even your statement _make sure the contents are never expanded again_ is IMO fuzzy. As a programmer, you always decide (by writing the program), what is going to happen. Everything, including parameter expansion, happens according to the language rule. If we don't know what the person who is using your variable `x` is doing with it, we can't say for sure that it is never re-evaluated. Maybe he is dumping the variable to a file and then sourcing the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252776/discussion-between-f-zer-and-user1934428).

Comment: Thank you, @Will Ness. That's perfectly clear.